# How to capture next tine after the certain previous line in the node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, fs, readline

Log file has certain string happening several time. I need to capture next line for all occurrences of this previous string with node.js.
For example content of the file:

```
Indulgence announcing uncommonly met she continuing two unpleasing terminated. Now busy say down the shed eyes roof paid her  
Compile Error  
./aaarty/bbb/cfvcc/dddhjklpi  
Course suffer to do he sussex it window advice. Yet matter enable misery end extent common men should. Her indulgence but assistance favourable cultivated everything collecting  
Compile Error  
./asshtyd/wrfber/ghn/fffh/gh/ikjmlk  
Extended kindness trifling remember he confined outlived if. Assistance sentiments yet unpleasing say  
Compile Error  
./cc/wwwasftbb/kkk/tgfh/pioqascfg/qqq  
Open they an busy they my such high  strong text
```

Using node.js I need to capture each line that goes after the line with the string "Compile Error"

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var array = 
fs.readFileSync('mylogfile.txt').toString().split("\n");
    for(let i in array) {
       if (array[i] == "Compilation Error")
          {
            let k = parseInt(i)+parseInt(1)
            console.log(array[k])
          }
    }
```